# convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx $

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I need help checking convergence of the integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx $$

I tried to change the integral to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx $ or comparing to other integrals but got stuck.

any suggestions?

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: and tomorrow it might rain on East Sweden. So?

Comment: i don't know if it will raines in East sweden, i'm not the Lord

Comment: It is interesting to notice how many mathematicians are affected by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_language_impairment ...

Answer (score 6):

A convergence check is much easier than evaluation, since for small $x$ the integrand is $O(1)$ and for large $x$ it's $O(xe^{-x})$, giving respective antiderivative behaviours $O(x)$ and $O(x^2e^{-x})$. To evaluate, rewrite as$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2xe^{-x}dx}{1-e^{-2x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty 2xe^{-(2k+1)x}dx=\sum_k\frac{2}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$(the last $=$ is equivalent to the Basel problem).

Answer (score 3):

As regards the convergence, you may note that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2x\cdot x^2}{e^x-e^{-x}}=0$$
It follows that there is $R>0$ such that for any $x\geq R$,
$$0<\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
Hence
$$0<\int_R^{+\infty}\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx\leq \int_R^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{R}.$$
P.S. Since $\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}$ is continuous in $(0,+\infty)$ with a finite limit at $0$ (it tends to $1$), the integral $\int_0^{R}\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$ is finite for any $R>0$.

Comment: what is the idea behind this? if you drop the R idea and calculate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}$ you get $\infty$ this makes me unsure about your way. can you explain?

Comment: The problem here is to check integrability in some half line $[R,+\infty)$, with $R>0$. For $[0,R]$ see my P.S.

Comment: thanks I understand now

Comment: actually, Im still not sure. the integral between 0 and R is finite if the integral limits are bounded and the function is bounded. when the integral on $\frac{1}{x^2}$ approaches 0 it goes to $\infty$  why it is okay to ignore that?

Comment: In the interval $[0,R]$ we consider the limit at 0 of $\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}$(not $1/x^2$).

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, you are right. I missed that detail.Thanks.

Comment: @segevp Any further doubt? I think it is clear now that the intervals $[0,R]$ and $[R,+\infty)$ are handled separately

Comment: @segevp If it makes it any clearer:
$$0<\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}<f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{x^2},&x\ge7\\1,&0<x<7\end{cases}$$And we use the direct comparison test to see that$$0<\int_0^\infty\frac{2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}~\mathrm dx<\int_0^\infty f(x)~\mathrm dx<\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the function

$$ f \, : x \in \, ]0,+\infty[ \; \longmapsto \; \frac{2x}{e^{x} - e^{-x}} $$

is continuous on $]0,+\infty[$.

**When $x \to 0$:**

$$ e^{x} - e^{-x} = \big( 1 + x + o(x) \big) - \big( 1 - x + o(x) \big) = 2x + o(x). $$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{2x}{e^{x} - e^{-x}} \; \mathop{\sim} \limits_{x \to 0} \; 1. $$

Since $x \mapsto 1$ is integrable, $f$ is integrable at $0$.

**When $x \to +\infty$:**

$$ \frac{2x}{e^{x} - e^{-x}} = \mathop{o} \limits_{x \to +\infty}\Big( \frac{1} {x^2} \Big) $$

It follows from Riemann's comparison theorem that $f$ is integrable at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You may also notice that since
$$ \frac{\sinh x}{x} = \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
we clearly have
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh x}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}.\tag{2} $$
Funny thing, the exact value of the given integral is just at the midpoint of $\left(0,\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right).$